# Find documents based on a property values progressively in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Assume I have a collection with many documents which they have a property called "status". Status accepts any Int value. I want to find all documents that have status with value "1". If there are not any, find all documents that have status with value "2" and so on... Is there any solution to do such action in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

That is possible.

If you create an index on `{status:1}`, you can run a query with `limit:1` and `sort:{status:1}`, and project to return only the status field (excluding _id).  This would be a covered query that is quite efficient and should only examine a single index key.

Then use that value to query for matching status.  This query would also use the index to minimize the number of document examined.

The difference between doing this in 2 queries vs 1 is likely small.

You could peform both in an aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort: {status: 1}},
  {$limit: 1},
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      status: 1
  }},
  {$lookup: {
      as: "matched",
      from: "collection",
      let: {target: "$status"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$status",
                "$$target"
              ]
            }
        }}
      ]
  }},
  {$unwind: "$matched"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$matched"}}
])
```

It is not completely clear whether the `$lookup` part will be able to use the index, so you should test to see if that actually performs better than running 2 queries from the client.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zDw_yzoCwlt)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I think I did not ask my question very well. Status values are not ascending! It can accept any value in any order. Like: ["s", 123, null, "John"]. Sort is not very handy in this situation. Also Status values length is not clear.